# How can I color the right side of a page?

Tags: color, books

I need some help, I would create a book and I need to color the right side of a page, but I don't know how can I do

[image: I need to make a gray line like this]

I need to make a gray line like this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

Code (inspired from someone on this pages):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for lorem ipsum
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\backgroundsetup{
    placement=center,
    scale=1,
    angle=0,
    opacity=.3,
    nodeanchor=center,
    contents={
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \draw[cyan, line width=2cm] 
            ($(current page.north east)$) -- ($(current page.south east)$);
            \
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{One}
    \lipsum
    \section{One-one}
    \lipsum[5-9]
    \section{One-two}
    \lipsum[10-15]
\end{document}
```

You can change color (here cyan) at yours wishes.

Comment: yes, like it, how can I do?

Comment: I have added the code after the picture.

Comment: If you like, you can also upvote my answer.